# post on facebook page wall as facebook admin through facebook php api

Tags: php, api, facebook, facebook-page

I would like to post feed to facebook page wall as page admin. I can publish post to facebook wall with publish_stream from fb php api, but it is just as a normal facebook user. May I know how can I do likewise as a page admin (meaning that the post publish from facebook page and not from other fb user on the page wall)? Thank you. It is urgent.

Regards,
Benjamin

Comment: Page might has more than just one admin - when you specify the uid, post is created with it. It may have changed, but before the new api simply replacing uid with page worked fine for this.

Comment: Hi, even i am trying to learn about posting to facebook page. I have created a facebook page, and through php, i need to post to this page. If you could share as to how you got it working, it be great. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just come across this question.  This was a know bug within the Graph API which has now been addressed.  There is an additional permission named manage_pages which has been added to the list of extended permissions.  If you request this permission as part of your authentication process then you should be up and running.

Further information can be found in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#impersonation) and the [bug fix](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10005) that has been put in place.

Answer (score 2):

it is mentioned [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/).
If you want to post to Page Wall as Page, use page id in the UID not in the target_id.

Pages can't post to other pages.

If you want to post to Page Wall as Application, use page id in the target_id, and the app id in the UID [here](http://www.bilgidostu.com)