# PHP - Post content to my facebook page (not wall / timeline)

Tags: php, facebook

Is there any facebook PHP api for posting content in my facebook page (not wall or timeline)? I need to post content from my website.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found answers for my question in Stackoverflow itself.

[Is there a Facebook API to publish content to the FaceBook page using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662419/is-there-a-facebook-api-to-publish-content-to-the-facebook-page-using-php)

[post on facebook page wall as facebook admin through facebook php api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009416/post-on-facebook-page-wall-as-facebook-admin-through-facebook-php-api)

Thanks friends and thanks to Stackoverflow.